# Django: how to give multiple categories to an item

Tags: django

i want to have one Post have multiple Categories kind of like Tags here's what i have already

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default="Non Categorized")
    Thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    Text = RichTextField(blank=False, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Overview = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    main_story = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return reverse('about', args=(str(self.id)))
        return reverse('home')
```

Comment: Use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) field instead of a `ForeignKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest wat is to convert the `ForeignKey` a `ManyToMany` field

Here is the django doc -> [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

So that your post model will be:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, attribute=name, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default="Non Categorized")
    Thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    Text = RichTextField(blank=False, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Overview = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    main_story = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```